# How to send mail from C# WPF project with yahoo bizmail

Tags: c#, wpf, yahoo-mail

I have developed a WPF Application from which I want to send email. But the client has yahoo bizmail as their mail vnedor. I'm using the following SMTP details. But the mail is not going.

```
SMPT Client: `smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com`
Port: 465
```

with proper credentials.

And I have set EnableSsl to true on SmtpClient object.

Here is the code:

```
        String FromMail = Convert.ToString(rowSettings["MailFrom"]).Trim();
        String Password = Convert.ToString(rowSettings["MailFromPassword"]).Trim();
        String Host = Convert.ToString(rowSettings["MailSMTPClient"]).Trim();
        String Port = Convert.ToString(rowSettings["MailSMTPPort"]).Trim();
        auth = new NetworkCredential(FromMail, Password);
        client = new SmtpClient(Host, Convert.ToInt32(Port));
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = auth;
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.SendAsync(mail, null);
```

Following is the exception:

An exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: What exception do you get? Show us the full code.

Comment: 1. You are not awaiting `SendAsync`. 2. Show use detailed exception message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the port that has to be used for smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com is 587 and not 465.